# Backbone.Subviews renders before subview fetches collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

This question concerns either an issue with BB.Subviews and me not knowing how to control when it renders the subview, or my code is designed incorrectly. My issue is one of my subviews fetches it's own collection of models. It then (is supposed to) renders this collection of models. My console.log lines show me that BB.subviews is rendering the child before it has finished fetching it's collection. Is there a BB.subview setting I'm not seeing in the instructions or is my design bad and I should be fetching the collection for the child and passing it in? The latter would work but seems wrong to me.

Here is at least one experieced BB coder that agrees with my design. [Fetch Collections withn Views](http://pwhisenhunt.com/2013/03/25/backbonejs-tips-patterns-and-best-practices.html#fetch-from-views).

In my older code (pre BB.subviews) the child subview called it's own render after it had finished fetching it's collection. I can't do this with BB.subviews.

Comment: Maybe I should have the child spawn a message after it finishes fetching. Then the parent can hear that message and start the render chain.

Comment: Damn can't do that either. The parent view has to kick off the render chain.

Comment: Any chance of seeing a demo? Some of us don't use BB.Subviews but might be able to figure it out anyway.

Comment: @muistooshort do you build the collections first then pass to the subviews? Or do your subviews build their own collections?

Comment: I've done both before but usually my collections are application level objects rather than view-specific objects (but not always).

Comment: In my mind, building the collection in a parent then passing to a subview breaks encapsulation. The child view is an object that displays a gallery of photos for a particular member. It makes sense that it would know how to retrieve the gallery by the member id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my answer is to drop Backbone.Subviews and Backbone.Courier. No offense to these awesome coders intended. None. I want to include all code (including fetching) relevant to the child view within the view, not pass it from the parent. I need to control when the child views render. The parent talks directly (calls their methods) to each child, the children use global messages to talk to their parent and siblings.